# Android: Facebook 3.0 SDK requests Galaxy S3 app permission

Tags: android, facebook, galaxy

I'm developing an Android app that is using the latest Facebook SDK (3.0) - When testing on a Galaxy S3; if I share via Facebook from my app, Facebook will launch and I'll get prompted to permission Samsung's Galaxy S3 FB app, not my own. This issue doesn't seem to exist on other Android devices.